# Matlab Data Average and new features extraction

Tags: matlab

I wrote a code where matlab will catch all the 5 th row of 117 data files from a specific folder and extract it to new features. The code worked. but now i want matlab to average every data files on that  specific folder and take the specific average datas from every data file and extract it to new features and save it as a one new data file. How can i do that.Here is the sample code of catching 5th row and extract it,what changes i have to make for average.

```
close all
clear all

file_location =  
emptyroomdata =fileDatastore(fullfile(file_location),'ReadFcn',@importdata,'FileExtensions','.csv')  
fullFileNames = emptyroomdata.Files ;
numfiles = length(fullFileNames)

data = readall(emptyroomdata) ;

maxi = [];
mini = [];
kur = [];
ske = [];
stan = [];

for k = 1:numfiles
h = data{k,1}.data(5,:) ; 
maxx = max(h) ;
minn = min(h) ;
kurt = kurtosis(h) ;
skee = skewness(h) ;
stdd = std(h) ;

maxi = [maxi, maxx] ;
maximum = maxi.' ;
mini = [mini, minn] ;
minimum = mini.' ;
kur = [kur, kurt] ;
kurto_sis = kur.' ;
ske = [ske skee] ;
skew_ness = ske.' ;
stan = [stan, stdd] ;
standard_deviation = stan.' ;
end
```

Comment: Stop spamming tags. Your question has nothing to do with any of those except [tag:matlab]. Please read the tag descriptions before using.

Comment: You can compute the average using either `mean` or `median`, depending on which type of average you need.